# How to Convert Image widget to Video Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

First I created image and then set background video and how we get download that whole widget to the video in flutter give any solution.

Comment: use this to embeded image in a video, https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

Comment: how to save particular widget as a video in flutter??

Comment: you still have this issue?